# How do I serve https and http for Jetty by one port

Tags: configuration, proxy, jetty, forward

What I want to do is serving http and https at the same time for my jetty application. I have SelectChannelConnector and SslSocketConnector connectors and their ports are 3131 and 8443 respectively.

I would like to transparently forward requests

```
http://localhost:80/* --> http://localhost:3131/*
https://localhost:80/* --> https://localhost:8443/*
```

What is the easiest way to make it?

Thanks

Comment: Note that browsers use port 443 by default for HTTPS requests. You would need to forward all port 80 requests to 3131 and all port 443 requests to 8443.

Comment: @Vortico Thanks. You helped me a lot.I have changed my default ports as you suggested. now I am listening 80 and 443 and it solved my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Vortico suggested, I changed my ports to 80 for http and 443 for https. It solved my problem.